# Java Execute task repeatedly - until timeout occurs or condition is fulfilled - Synchronous execution

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I am currently facing a specific problem, for which I am not sure how to tackle it. Let me 
briefly describe this problem:

- In a method I have to call another method and process its response
- If this response equals a certain value, I continue with the regular execution
- Otherwise, I wait for x seconds (e.g. 2 seconds) and call the method again to process its response again
- The last step is repeated until a certain period of time expired or the method delivers the intended response. 
  Thus, in total I shall not wait forever but just e.g. at max 10 seconds to see if the method returns the intended response in that 
  time.
- Remark: If the method does not need 10 seconds to deliver the intended result, the regular
  execution should continue immediately after that. This means that I don't want to wait 10 seconds 
  if the result is there after e.g. 2 seconds.

Just using "old-school" means I came up with a solution such as the following (partly pseudo-code to simplify)

```
//No exception handling to simplify method
public ComplexValuePart mainMethod(int id) {
    //Other code executed before

    int maxAmountTries = 5;
    int waitTime = 2000;

    int counter = 0;
    boolean conditionFulfilled = false;
    ComplexValue cv = null;
    while (counter++ < maxAmountTries && !conditionFulfilled) {
        cv = calculatingMethod(id);
        if (cv.conditionHolds()) {
            conditionFulfilled = true;
        } else {
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
        }
    }

    if (counter == maxAmountTries && !conditionFulfilled) {
        //report error
    }

    //Continue processing with cv
    return doThingsWithCV(cv);
}

public ComplexValue calculatingMethod(int id) {
    //Implementation not relevant here
}
```

However, using Java 8 (this is my restriction right now) I thought there might be other/better solutions for this?

As an alternative I came up with something using a ScheduledExecutorService e.g.:

```
public void mainMethod(int id) {
    //Other code executed before
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    Future<?> future = service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {           
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ComplexValue cv = calculatingMethod(id);
            if (cv.conditionHolds()) {
                //shutdown service including awaitTermination
            }                
        }
    }, 0, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    try {
        future.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
        //shutdown service including awaitTermination
    }

    //Continue processing with cv - How can I access cv here?
}
```

For returning the `ComplexValue` I guess I need to use `Callable` instead of `Runnable`? Can I do it accordingly with `Callable`?
Moreover, it always ran into the timeout even if the condition in the service execution was OK before.
In this case I don't know whether this all is a bit too much "overhead" for implementing such a quite simple task.
What are the benefits of such a solution versus plain `Thread sleep`?

Is there some Java 8 functionality that I am missing to implement this part?

To note: I don't have to execute different tasks in parallel in this loop. The execution of the main Method shall not continue 
until the timeout is expired or the desired result is there - thus, no `async` execution.
The method in place needs to return some data based on the response from the service call.

Answer (score 6):

I'd use TimerTask instead. It repeats executing the "run" method every "waitTime" milliseconds. You can specify when to stop repeating this task by calling "timer.cancel()"

```
public void mainMethod(int id) {
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        int counter = 0;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            cv = calculatingMethod(id);
            if (cv.conditionHolds() || counter++ > countLimit) {
                // conditionFulfilled = true;
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0, waitTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. But in this case the code following timer.schedule...is continued without waiting for the timer. Thus, in this case I need additional measures to make sure the part only continues until timeout expired or condition is fulfilled right? Moreover, should not in general a ScheduledExecutorService be used instead of a Timer?

Comment: The code to be executed after the condition is met should be inside the if statement (line # 10 my code). ScheduledExecutorService has some advantages over Timer, but with Timer, you can get much cleaner code, and there is not much difference in terms of performance when not using multi-threading.

Comment: But if mainMethod needs to return something based on cv, it won't work like that - correct? This is the case in my situation.I will update the original question to point this out (right now the code would not reflect this)

Comment: No, it won't. In this case, you may try recursion.

public static int mainMethod(int id, int triesCount) throws InterruptedException {
        cv = calculatingMethod(id);
        
        if (!cv.conditionHolds() && triesCount < triesLimit) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            return mainMethod(id, triesCount + 1);
        }
        
        // some logic        
        return 0;
    }

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but how does this help in this case? If there is a caller of mainMethod, he will receive 0 as a result (or some other value except for the real value if the condition is not fulfilled immediately. Sorry for the additoinal questions but right now I don't think this will solve the issue. Anyway, thanks for your fast replies and your answer.

Comment: Of course, you'll have to change the 0 to something based on cv. The return statement will only be reached if the condition is fulfilled or triesCount is reached. Otherwise, the mainMethod will call itself recursively each 1 second. You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

```
final long deadline = System.currentTimeMillis() + TIMEOUT_MS;

boolean done;
Result result;
do {
  result = doSomething();
  done = resultIsOk(result);
  if ( !done ) {
    final long msRemaining = deadline - System.currentTimeMillis();
    if ( msRemaining > 0 ) {
      Thread.sleep(Math.min(msRemaining, RETRY_WAIT_TIME_MS);
    } else {
      done = true;
    }
  }
} while (!done);

if ( !resultIsOk(result) ) {
  // Error or something.
}
```

This code will keep calling `doSomething()` until it returns the expected value *or* `TIMEOUT_MS` milliseconds have passed. Assuming that `doSomething()` returns quickly, it will never take more than `TIMEOUT_MS` (plus maybe a few milliseconds). Also, the inter-retry delay is constant and independent of the run time of `doSomething()` (will retry every 2 seconds even if `doSomething()` runs for 1.9 seconds), and the worst case time it takes is `TIMEOUT_MS` + the time one call to `doSomething()` takes.

It may be beneficial to implement the waiting/timeout logic in its own class `Timeout`. Then you can create an instance for a given timeout period and pass it on through different layers so that even the lowest layer (e.g. network IO) can set its timeout value appropriately to not exceed the deadline defined by a top layer of application logic.

Combine that `Timeout` class with polymorphic `RetryStrategies` and you have a very flexible way to specify and handle many different scenarios.

Using lambdas, you can even create a fully generic encapsulation of the full retry logic, like

```
<R> R retryForResult( Supplier<R> functionToCall, Function<R,Boolean> resultValidationFunction, long maxTimeMs, Iterable<Long> retryDelays );
```

Comment: Thanks JimmyB. I guess this one is similar to my first "solution" with the main difference that you don't wait a max number of tries but you are using a timeout directly (and then work on this using "- System.currentTimeMillis" right?

Comment: Correct. I basically just made the timeout more explicit and a little more flexible because the total timeout is now independent of the inter-retry delay. (E.g. timeout of 10s with retry delay of 3s. You can also use some back-off strategy or some other way of varying inter-retry delays without changing the rest of the logic.)